# ADB and CMD not cooperating

Tags: android, cmd, adb, hta

i have a program called KindleSuite (kfsowi.com)

This program which is an HTA has an integrated CMD console which is console.txt
The following is my attempt to check whether a backup of the decive already exists and if so to restore it.
If the backup does not exist the console should tell the user then close the script, but instead it is continuing to the restore section, which in turn appears to be ignoring the wait-for-device command.
Can anyone give me an idea why this isnt functioning correctly?

```
@echo off
if NOT exist resources\scripts\backup\backup.ab (
echo No Backup Available... >resources\console.txt
exit
)
echo Restoring Backup. Please confirm on Kindle's screen...>resources\console.txt
resources\tools\adb wait-for-device restore resources\scripts\backup\backupdata.ab
echo Restore complete. >resources\console.txt
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I don't see anything immediately wrong with the code, but does it work if you use an IF/ELSE structure instead?

```
@echo off
IF NOT EXIST resources\scripts\backup\backup.ab (
echo No Backup Available... >resources\console.txt
exit
) ELSE (
echo Restoring Backup. Please confirm on Kindle's screen...>resources\console.txt
resources\tools\adb wait-for-device restore resources\scripts\backup\backupdata.ab
echo Restore complete. >resources\console.txt
exit
)
```

Comment: It does not (that was how i wrote it originally). Im actually realizing that may not be the issue. In the hta there is a backup and restore button with id's backup and bak_restore respectively, which each have their own onclick vbscripts that run .cmd's with the same respective names.            Ive double checked and both buttons are named and pointing to the correct scripts and the scripts open the correct cmd's but the restore buttom is echoing output from the backup.cmd

Comment: Ah, okay, that makes sense. I've been playing with your code for a few minutes and it all seems to do what you'd expect it to, so I seriously doubt the fault is in the code itself. Most likely it's a bug in the calling application, not the script, like you said.

Comment: <SCRIPT FOR="backup" EVENT="onClick" LANGUAGE="VBScript">
        Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        WshShell.Run "cmd /k resources\scripts\backup\backup.cmd", 0, false
      </SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT FOR="bak_restore" EVENT="onClick" LANGUAGE="VBScript">
        Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        WshShell.Run "cmd /k resources\scripts\backup\restore.cmd", 0, false
      </SCRIPT>

<input type='button' class="button" id='backup' value='Backup Device' /><br /><br />
<input type='button' class="button" id='bak_restore' value='Restore Backup' />

i dont understand how

Comment: Well, I have zero VBScript experience but that looks fine to me.. Perhaps you should have the buttons run CMD scripts that are just echo statements, to make sure that they really are running what they're supposed to? Aside from that, I have no idea.